# INSERT INTO using sqlite with python

Tags: python, sqlite

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO REDDIT_USER (USERNAME, CREATED_DATE) VALUES ('PHILZEEY', '08-09-17')")
```

This top one works.

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO {tn} (USERNAME, CREATED_DATE) VALUES ({nm}, {dt})'.format(tn='REDDIT_USER', nm='John', dt='09-09-17'))
```

This bottom one doesn't.

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: BTW the reason I want to do the bottom one is because I'll be passing in some arguments that will change. I can't have them constant like the top one.

Comment: what is the error you're getting ? it will be helpful to debug

Comment: You forgot to place the quotes around column values. Also, you should not insert this way. Instead, you need to use parameters.

Comment: Could you give me an example what you mean i should be doing instead. @mshsayem

Comment: See the answer of Tim below.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using prepared statements with positional parameters:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO REDDIT_USER (USERNAME, CREATED_DATE) VALUES (?, ?)", ('John', '2017-09-09'))
```

With regard to making the table name a parameter, this isn't possible, even from a prepared statement.  In general, most queries would not run on a different table.  And allowing the table name to be changed like this could represent a security risk.  If you need to query two different tables, then create two prepared statements for those tables.

By the way, you said that the top one works:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO REDDIT_USER (USERNAME, CREATED_DATE) VALUES ('PHILZEEY', '08-09-17')")
```

Actually, while this might *execute*, it almost certainly is not date data you want to be inserting into your SQLite database.  Dates are stored as regular text and should almost always be stored in an ISO format, with the year, followed by the month and day.  For example, you could use `'2017-09-08'` as a date literal, but don't use `'08-09-17'`.

Comment: Yeah the dates were just general, I have a proper date format for them. But i'll go ahead and try what you suggested, thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd one doesn't have quotes around the inserted values.  Try this:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO {tn} (USERNAME, CREATED_DATE) VALUES ('{nm}', '{dt}')".format(tn='REDDIT_USER', nm='John', dt='09-09-17'))
```